# Circle border-width percentage?

Tags: css

I have a transparent css circle with border-width of 5px so it look like just an outline, my circle size is 100% x 100% (dynamic depending on the parent div) and it works great.

I want my border-width to also get bigger/smaller depending on the circle size! Is that possible? I could not set my border-width with percentage! how else can I do this?

I am trying to keep this CSS only please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to do this using SVGs, I do not think there is an easy way to do this with CSS alone

I used this article to help me, very easy if I use SVG images

http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_circle.asp